# CodeIgnite Mysql Dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have a problem that i can't fix :(

Well, I have 2 dates and 2 times.

- 1 date to start publish
- 1 date to finish publish
- 1 time to start publish
- 1 time to end publish

what I need?
Show the more recent record, that

- start publish date is current
- end publish date is not finished
- start publish time is current
- end publish time is not finished

I tried with

```
start date >= date('Y-m-d') AND
finish date <= date('Y-m-d') AND
(start time) >= date('H:i:s') AND
end time <= date('H:i:s'))

order by ('finish date', 'desc');
```

In codeIgniter..

```
->where("start_date >= '{$today}' AND finish_date <= '{$today}'")
 ->where("start_time >= '{$time}' AND finish_time <= '{$time}'")
```

what i miss?

Thanks

Comment: probably you want to use `NOW()` in order to compare all these dates with current datetime (now today)?

Comment: $start _date variable issues please check this

Comment: and what is this code? SQL or PHP? there is some mixture into syntax or is some very fancy approach.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK that I fix it...

```
(start_date >= $today AND start_time <= $time) AND
(finish_date <= $today AND end_time >= $time)
```

Well, that works atm...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the active recods query 
from

```
$this->select(*)->from('table')->where("start_date >= '{$today}' AND finish_date <= '{$today}'")
 ->where("start_time >= '{$time}' AND finish_time <= '{$time}'")
```

to

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date BETWEEN {$today} AND finish_date BETWEEN {$today} AND start_time BETWWEN {$time} AND finish_time BETWWEN {$time}");

return $this->db->get()->result();
```